# Concatenate string properties of an object with lambda

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, lambda

Please consider the following:

```
public class MyObject
{
   public bool B;
   public string Txt;
}

List<MyObject> list; //list of a bunch of MyObject's
```

With lambda expression, how can I produce a string consisting of comma separated values of Txt of those objects, where B is true?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

for .net 3.5:

```
string.Join(",", list.Where(o => o.B).Select(o => o.Txt).ToArray())
```

for .net 4.0:

```
string.Join(",", list.Where(o => o.B).Select(o => o.Txt))
```

Comment: with .net 4, you don't need `.ToArray()`.

Comment: I need this but for visual Basic .net

Comment: @Luis `String.Join(",", list.Where(Function(x) x.B).Select(Function(x) x.Txt))`

Answer (score 3):

```
string myString = string.Join(",", list.Where(x => x.B).Select(x=>x.Txt));
```

Answer (score -2):

```
var strFinal = "";
myList.ForEach(pq => strFinal += ", " + pq.ItemId);
```